# Show <select>'s drop-down options list window with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to somehow show the options of the selects on hover intead of on click.
I have seen some questions related to this but they are pretty old and don't work.

Is it possible nowadays to do such a simple task without creating a custom select?
You can see in my code that I tried some solutions I found but none of them worked:

```js
const selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select")

for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
  selects[i].onchange = function() {
    if (selects[i].value) selects[i].style.color = "green";
  }
  selects[i].onmouseenter = function() {
    console.log("show select's options");
    // selects[i].click();
    /*
    var event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    selects[i].dispatchEvent(event);
    */
  }
  selects[i].onmouseout = function() {
    // console.log("hide select's options");
    if (document.activeElement === selects[i]) {
      selects[i].blur();
      selects[i].focus();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
option {
  color: green;
}

option:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}

select {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Letters</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
  <option>d</option>
  <option>e</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option>Numbers</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option>Symbols</option>
  <option>!</option>
  <option>"</option>
  <option>#</option>
  <option>$</option>
  <option>%</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have faced this problem a few weeks ago. Kinda difficult if not impossible to have such funcionality working in all browsers and maintain it for the future, as some browsers relay it to the OS and such. Definitely go with your own selector or use a selector library (jqWidgets, for example, has one, altough I don't like them much).

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález - What if I only need it for the current Google Chrome version?

Comment: Oh, that's better. Going to check around.

Comment: Nope. Can't find nothing. Let's see if someone else has something.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález - Yup, I couldn't find it too. These types of customization limits in things that should totally be customizable annoys me every time I find one.